# How to remove or unbind jQuery Handler from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this function to trigger a mobile responsive nav. I would like to destroy this function based upon a certain browser width. I am uncertain on how to do this on an event that I did not bind using the jQuery bind() function.

See example below:

```
$(function() {

    //update the width value when the browser is resized (useful for devices which switch from portrait to landscape)
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var current_width = $(window).width();
        if(current_width < 400){                    
            $('nav#menu').mmenu();
        }if(current_width > 401){
            $('body').('nav#menu'),mmenu().die();
        }
    });
```

Here is an example of the menu:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about/team">The team</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about/team/management">Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about/team/development">Development</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What function are you trying to unbind?  The resize event or some click event?  if it's the click event on the menu elements then probably something like this `$('body').('nav#menu').off('click');`

Answer (score 0):

The off trigger will unbind your event

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).innerWidth() < 400){       
      $('#width').html($(window).innerWidth());            
    }else{
        $(window).off('resize',function(){
            //optional Handler
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the code below:
if(current_width > 401){
$(window).off('resize',function(){});
}

Comment: If you don't need the handler you can remove it:
`$(window).off('resize');`

Comment: I am trying to resize the browser and have the menu be shown in a responsive format and vice versa. Not necessarily on window load which would require a page refresh. I am new to jQuery and am unsure how to add the proposed solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery  off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(window).off('resize');
```

**Working Example**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7wvk04y/)

make the output window small before clicking run to see it work as shown here:
[image]

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        var current_width = $(window).innerWidth();
        if(current_width < 400){       
          $('#width').html($(window).innerWidth());            
        }else{
            $(window).off('resize')
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: thank you. But I am still having issues. The menu item that I am attempting to destroy is this $('nav#menu').mmenu(); I'd like to call that when the browser is less than 480px and destroy but destroy that when the browser is resized to something larger than 480px...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go is with [jQuery.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function as it is the new recommended way.

You can also use [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), that works the same but is to be deprecated one day (as of v1.7 of jQuery)